# Remote desktop with OpenGL?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, android, vnc, opengl

From an Android tablet, I want to remotely access Windows 3D applications (primarily [Rhino 3D](http://www.rhino3d.com/)).

*Is it possible to have a 3D application send the OpenGL commands via the network to a client on the Android tablet?*

Of course, many 3D applications can be run without hardware 3D acceleration, but then display updates are slow, especially via RDP or VNC. Sending OpenGL commands should be considerably faster than sending rendered bitmaps.